# Django local_settings.py Protection and Permission

Tags: python, django, linux, security

I want deploy a Django project, I created a local_settings.py for local variables(secret_key, database ,etc). Are there any best practices or check lists for protecting local_settings.py file?
for example what should be its permission (e.g is 700 ok?)? or where should be located (its path)?
Thanks

Comment: After some months, I find out "Two Scoops of Django" book very useful. I recommend this book for such questions.

Answer (score 0):

Django has a deployment check-list that should help you deploy your project [Django Deployment Checklist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/) as for the server itself [How To Set Up Django with Postgres, Nginx, and Gunicorn on Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: thank you so much, but I need details about a local_settings.py file not deploying steps.

Comment: The first protection is having a secure server with a proper credentials, permission regarding a file in your server is secondary, if someone has access to your server that won't change a thing.
As the two links above suggest, best security practice is to have different settings (prod and local) and keep your variables in a .env file. 
Read carefully the two links